# TomEE: single class loader per EAR + parent last

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader, apache-tomee

Is there a way to configure TomEE to use single class loader per EAR and load classes from the application first and server last?

Answer (score 1):

not sure i get very well your question since if you have a single classloader there is no need of first/last notion

BTW, currently TomEE only supports a classloader for lib part then one tomcat webappclassloader by webapp as child of the lib one.

Comment: I have this issue where a third-party app is deployed as an EAR, consisting of several WARs. I've added a Rest webapp as a new WAR there, in which code the API of the mentioned third-party app is being used. Then, as I make a request in my rest webapp where this API is used, that API is being loaded (is in EAR's APP-INF/lib dir) by a different classloader than the one that loaded them already on TomEE server startup. My SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888074/same-class-loaded-by-different-classloaders-rest-service-deployed-as-a-war-with#comment137335618_77888074